# Type Script: Array<Object> vs Object[]

Tags: typescript

In Typescript what is the difference between these assignments:

```
var Object[];
var Array<Object>
```

Does generics in Type Script has the same semantic meaning as in languages like Java or is it simply syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's just sugar. `Object[]` and `Array<Object>` are exactly the same in TypeScript.

One way to check this is to write this code:

```
var x: Object[];
var x: Array<Object>;
```

Duplicate variable declarations must have exactly the same type, so the lack of error here implies that the types are identical.

Comment: Which one is the sugar in this case?  Any thoughts?